# O valor "null" ocupa menos espaço na memória do que "0"?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Sou novo com banco de dados e aprendi que a economia de espaço em disco é essencial, queria entender se o valor "null" ocupa o mesmo espaço que "0" na memória.

Comment: Entenda antes que NULL é diferente de 0 , campo "temperatura" por exemplo , 0 é uma informação , existe temperatura 0 , null é ausência de informação. Eu não me preocuparia com isto, mas deve ter alguma literatura sobre isto.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556363/space-used-by-nulls-in-database